# how to add custom style to active tab in createbottomtabnavigrtor

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

hello guys hope ur fine i am working with a react native project with createBottomTabNavigator in react-navigation 4 and i need to customise the active tab by adding a border top with some size and color 
and this is my code how can i do it ?

```
const Navigation = createBottomTabNavigator({
 test1: test1,
 test2: test2,
 ProfileScreen: ProfileScreen,
},{
 initialRouteName: 'ProfileScreen',
 tabBarOptions: {
   activeTintColor: '#BFC932',
   inactiveTintColor: '#333',
 }
}
)
```

how to add style to the active tab only ? and thx

Answer (score 0):

this is how i achieved to change the icons to the ones only active tab:

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: AppStack,
    Notification: Notifications,
    Account: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) =>
        getTabBarIcon(navigation, focused, tintColor),
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: colors.tealC,
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  },
);
```

ive created the bottomTabnavigator and ive called getTabBarIcon function ,

// this function gives the icons when tab is selected

```
const getTabBarIcon = (navigation, focused, tintColor) => {
  const {routeName} = navigation.state;
  if (routeName === 'Home') {
    if (focused) {
      return (
        <Image
          style={homeStyles.bottomTabI}
          source={require('./app/assets/images/homeF.png')}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Image
          style={homeStyles.bottomTabI}
          source={require('./app/assets/images/unstar.png')}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  if (routeName === 'Notification') {
    if (focused) {
      return (
        <Image
          style={homeStyles.bottomTabI}
          source={require('./app/assets/images/whatsapp.png')}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Image
          style={homeStyles.bottomTabI}
          source={require('./app/assets/images/bellNF.png')}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  if (routeName === 'Account') {
    if (focused) {
      return (
        <Image
          style={homeStyles.bottomTabI}
          source={require('./app/assets/images/whatsapp.png')}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Image
          style={homeStyles.bottomTabI}
          source={require('./app/assets/images/profileNF.png')}
        />
      );
    }
  }
};
```

so here basically route name first checks if its that route name and if its that, then according to if(focused) im adding the icons. hope you can do the same with the styling when active tab is selected.

Hope it helps.feel free for doubts.